# MySQL error doesnt make sense?

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont know SQL, but I need to use it for PHP, and I have a problem. When I try to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
userbeinglogged VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
action_location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
log_date DATE('YYYY-MM-DD') NOT NULL,
log_time TIME('00:00:00') NOT NULL,
 );
```

At the last line, I get the error `"A closing bracket was expected (near')')"`. 
I don't see the problem. Also, I'm pretty sure the `DATE` and `TIME` functions are incorrect, so if you could help me out with the syntax of those that would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your comma, right before the closing parenthesis.

And for advice just use `log_Date DATETIME`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma. Looks like it has an extra.

```
CREATE TABLE logs ( userbeinglogged VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, action_location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, log_date DATE('YYYY-MM-DD') NOT NULL, log_time TIME('00:00:00') NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing comma. Change it to this.

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
  userbeinglogged VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  action_location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  log_date DATE('YYYY-MM-DD') NOT NULL,
  log_time TIME('00:00:00') NOT NULL
 );
```